# Axios one step behind vue's v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I've trouble finding out why my method logs the step before the actual one. So If I select 1 in a box and then 2, I'll get printed out nothing then 1.

Here is my code :

```
<b-form-select @input="setCadeauOrReduction(vGiftCard)" @change="calculateNet(vGiftCard)" v-if="this.cadeauOrReduction != 'reduction'" v-model="vGiftCard" id="bonCadeauSoin">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option v-for="boncadeau in boncadeaus" :key="boncadeau.id" v-bind:value="boncadeau.id">
                                        <p>N° </p>
                                        {{boncadeau.serialNumberProduct}}
                                        <p>|</p>
                                        {{boncadeau.amountOfCard}}
                                        <p>CHF</p>
                                    </option>
                                </b-form-select>
```

This basically calls the function @change. It gives me the Gift card's id as parameter. Then the function it calls :

```
fetchOneBonCadeau(idToFetch)
        {
            axios.get('/bonCadeaus/' + idToFetch)
            .then((res) => { 
                this.bonCadeauPourAxios = res.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })

            return this.bonCadeauPourAxios;
        },

        //Calculer montant net
        calculateNet(value)
        {
            console.log(this.fetchOneBonCadeau(value));


            if(this.vReasonReduction)
            {   
                this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut - this.vCostBrut * this.vReasonReduction.reductionAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut;
            }
        }
```

The console.log part always lags one step behind. I can't figure why. This is my controller if needed :

```
public function show($id)
{

    $bonCadeau = BonCadeau::where('id', $id)->first();

    return $bonCadeau;
}
```

Edit : normal code using the vModel binding property

```
fetchOneBonCadeau(idToFetch)
        {
            axios.get('/bonCadeaus/' + idToFetch)
            .then((res) => { 
                this.bonCadeauPourAxios = res.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })     
        },

        //Calculer montant net
        calculateNet(value)
        {
           this.fetchOneBonCadeau(value);

            console.log(this.bonCadeauPourAxios); //Is one step behind, first value is empty

            if(this.vReasonReduction)
            {   
                this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut - this.vCostBrut * this.vReasonReduction.reductionAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut;
            }
        }
```

I feel like vGiftCard is updated after the function "calculateNet" is called

Comment: as per my knowledge `return this.bonCadeauPourAxios;` should be inside axios `.then`. For ex: `axios.get('/bonCadeaus/' + idToFetch)
            .then((res) => { 
                this.bonCadeauPourAxios = res.data
                return this.bonCadeauPourAxios;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pradeepb but it returns undefined. Furthermore, the return was a desperate try to get it working. If it didn't lag one step behind, I would simply take the "this.bonCadeauPourAxios" value

Comment: I would try this If I were you. https://pastebin.com/gTcnnb9p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the result of the HTTP request returned by Axios is asynchronous, you will not obtain it right away in the `fetchOneBonCadeau` function.

What you can do however is return the axios promise from `fetchOneBonCadeau` and use it in `calculateNet`.

So you can implement `fetchOneBonCadeau` like this:

```
fetchOneBonCadeau(idToFetch)
{
    return axios.get('/bonCadeaus/' + idToFetch)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })     
},
```

And `calculateNet` like this:

```
calculateNet(value)
{
    this.fetchOneBonCadeau(value).then( (bonCadeauPourAxios) => {
        console.log(bonCadeauPourAxios);

        if(this.vReasonReduction)
        {   
            this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut - this.vCostBrut * this.vReasonReduction.reductionAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            this.vCostNet = this.vCostBrut;
        }
    });
   )
}
```

Implementing the logic using the `bonCadeauPourAxios` variable in the "`then`" callback guaranties that the variable will have been retrieved from the backend.

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of Axios being asynchronous but I didnt' know It wouldn't make it in time to update. I just believe the last parenthesis is an error